# Nginx: redirecting a directory to a virtual server

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have two Nginx virtual servers:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name antergos1;
    root /data/
    }

server {
    server_name     nagios;
    root            /usr/share/nagios/share;
    }
```

Now, I need to access the `http://nagios` server when requesting `http://antergos1/nagios`. Do I need to specify a proxy_pass and/or a rewrite for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either a proxy_pass or rewrite rule would work for that.

Comment: thanks! Can you provide an example of what the correct syntax would be?

Comment: `rewrite ^/nagios/(.*)$ http://nagios/$1;`

Comment: The rewrite rule works fine, thanks. However, I really need to reverse-proxy the nagios server in order to access it from outside the LAN. I tried 
        location /nagios {
 proxy_pass http://nagios.bellaria/;
 }
which proxies to the correct site but then the requested files are not found. Do I need to have both proxy_pass and rewrite of some kind? Sorry for the n00b question...